# Getting matching table information with solenium in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, matching, webautomation

I am writing a web automation bot with solenium in python 3.8 that pulls sales data from an admin interface, to send a message through the admin interface to thank them for a purchase. The sales are held in a table with the following structure.

```
<tr id="sale_row">
  <td>Month | Day | Year | time of sale</td>
  <td>Customer name | <a href="Link to message customer">Message Customer</a></td>
  <td>item Purchased</td>
  <td>Purchase Amount</td>
</tr>
```

I only want to send the message to orders made in the last x amount of days (this is what is causing the issue as I can't seem to link the dates to the href).

So far I have managed to select just the dates that I wanted to retrieve, but cant work out how to get the second td containing the href to the messaging system.

To match the dates I made a string that matches the format of their time stamp, then ran a for loop over the wanted range of days and appended the output to a list, and another loop that runs through the page pulling the dates and and then comparing them to the list of wanted dates and checking for a match. ( the dates are held in the 1st td which is the only one with a class that is "text-left"

```
    cm = today_date.strftime("%b")
    cd = today_date.day
    target_day = cd - 7
    days = range(target_day,cd+1)    
    sold_month = bot.find_elements_by_class_name("text-left")
    target_days = []
    active_sales =[]
    for day in days:
        target_date = target_days.append(cm+' '+str(day)+','+' '+str(cy))
    for month in sold_month:
        sale=active_sales.append(month.text[:-10]) 
    for active_sale in active_sales: 
        #print("Active sale:",active_sale)
        for target_day in target_days:
         #   print("Target Day:",target_days)
            if target_day == active_sale:
                print("Result:", active_sale)
```

The above provides selects only the days wanted without issue. To get the href to the messaging system on the second td I tried the following within the last if statement, it returns all of the links for every sale, which makes sense, but I cannot seem to work out how to get the messaging system's href out of the second td based on the 1st td being within the date range:

```
sales = bot.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/Inbox/New/")]')
```

All of the messaging links are different as they contain the customer ID, which is why they need to be matched to the date.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out getting the tr elements with xpath and then looping through those to grab the td's in each tr. And then slicing the sub strings to get the info I needed from each td